# Prototype vs. Not, what are benefits?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Here I made two objects; one has accessor methods created in the constructor, the other in the prototype. Why would one choose one of these over the other?

```
function spy1(name){
  this.name = name;
  var secret;
  this.setSecret = function(message){
    secret = message;
  };
  this.getSecret = function(){
   return secret;
  };
}

function spy2(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.secret;
  /* (see comment) was:
  var secret;
  */
}
spy2.prototype.setSecret = function(message){
  this.secret = message;
  /*was:
  secret = message;
  */
};
spy2.prototype.getSecret = function(){
  return this.secret;

  /*was:
  return secret;
  */
};

bond = new spy1("007");
smart = new spy2("86");

bond.setSecret("CONTROL is a joke.");
smart.setSecret("The British Secret Service is for sissies.");
```

Comment: Note that in your prototype case, you are (presumably inadvertently) creating an implicit global variable `secret` which has nothing whatsoever to do with the declared (and unused) `secret` variable in your constructor function. That global variable (a property of the global object), being global, will be shared by all instances of `spy2` -- which I'm guessing is not what you were trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed inadvertent. I changed the code; is this now correct? 
So really, a prototype can't modify variables private to the object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primordial differrence is that in your first example, without prototype, the `getSecret` and `setSecret` function implementation will reside on *every* instance of spy1.

On your second example, the functions are defined on the prototype, and all instances refer to them directly, you can test it:

```
var bond = new spy1("007"),
    bond2 = new spy1("007");

bond.getSecret === bond2.getSecret; // <-- false since they are two functions

var smart = new spy2("86"),
    smart2 = new spy2("86");


smart.getSecret === smart2.getSecret; // <-- true since is the same function
                                      // on all instances
```

Also note what @T.J. commented, in your second example, using the prototype, you don't have access to the constructor function closure, and for that you are making a `window.secret` global variable.

If you intend to work with [privileged methods](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html), extending the prototype is not an option, all the methods that need access to the variables defined within the scope of the constructor function need to be declared inside of it...

See also: [Closures](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml).

Comment: ...which (for the questioner's benefit) has serious memory usage ramifications and should be avoided if possible.

The non-prototype version does have the advantage that you can have truly private instance vars, because the member functions are closures.  (Although not in the way that it's done in the questioner's question.)

Comment: It may have serious memory usage ramifications, but if you're only creating a small number of instances, you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 5):

In your first example, you're creating new functions for *each* instance of the object whenever you instantiate a new one.  In the second, only a single copy of the function is created which is used by *all* the instances.

The second way can save memory.  You can also use [prototype chaining](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~atk/JavaScript/manuals/jsobj/) to implement inheritance.

Btw, your second example won't work as written.  the `secret` variable in `spy2` is local to the constructor.  In the `setSecret` and `getSecret` functions in the prototype, you're accessing a single global variable.

Comment: Ah, I see. So if I really want private variables, I can't use the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

With the second version you end up with a cleaner "constructor".

Comment: Yes, and I also end up with things which are related to the class sort of floating out there by themselves, not visibly a part of the class. That bothers me a just little bit.