# Is using a function to create an object in javascript as good as using the new operator

Tags: javascript

I have been using the following template to create objects in javascript.

```
function FileSpec(directory, filename){
  var object = {};
  object.full_path = function(){
    return directory + '/' + filename;
  }
  return object;
}

var filespec = FileSpec('tmp', 'index.html');
```

Are there any particular disadvantages in using the above implementation versus using prototype and new?

```
function FileSpec(directory, filename){
  this.directory = directory;
  this.filename = filename;
}

FileSpec.prototype.full_path = function(){
  return this.directory + '/' + this.filename
}

var filespec = new FileSpec('tmp', 'index.html');
```

Comment: Here is what you are looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319325/prototype-vs-not-what-are-benefits

Comment: The prototype is property and can be accessed on instances of FileSpec it's the better way if there a many instances of that object

Comment: Give this a read: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation

Comment: thanks for the resources,  I'll try out using 'new' and get the benefits it brings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't use the `instanceof` operator, or the [`Object.isPrototypeOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) effectively with 1, but you can with #2.

   ```
   filespace instanceof FileSpec; // false with 1, true with 2
   Filespec.isPrototypeOf(filespace); //false with 1, true with 2
   ```
2. When using `prototype` inheritance, prototype members (methods etc) are defined only once on the prototype. In #1, you're defining a new group of members on each instance, which is more memory intensive.

   ```
   var ar = [];

   for (var i=0;i<10000000;i++) {
       ar.push(FileSpec('tmp', 'index.html'));
   }

   // check memory usage, cry.
   ```

   Compared to:

   ```
   var ar = [];

   for (var i=0;i<10000000;i++) {
       ar.push(new FileSpec('tmp', 'index.html'));
   }

   // check memory usage.
   ```

Comment: also, the prototype property is set to Filespec for #2 and the values for this are also different.